# Modification to jQuery script to let me choose which is the default value of the select list on page entrance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make use of Mobiscroll jQuery script for a prettier input by the users. On page load, the first option of the select list is shown as selected. What should I add to the existing code that on page entrance, the (for example) 3rd value is shown as the default?

I tried `selecte="selected"` but it does not work.

this is the jQuery script

```
$(function(){
    $('#city').scroller({
        preset: 'select',
        theme: 'android-ics',
        display: 'inline',
        mode: 'scroller',
    });
});
```

and here is the options of the select box

```
<select id="city" class="cities" data-role="none" name="City">
<option value="">All</option>
<option value="1">Atlanta</option>
<option value="2">Berlin</option>
<option value="3">Boston</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily set the value from jQuery by doing this:

```
var defaultValue = 3;
$("#city").val(defaultValue);​
```

"3" here represents Boston from your drop down list, here's a fiddle for proof:

http://jsfiddle.net/6mj8n/5/

Comment: Even though when I submit it sends the 3rd option, the Mobiscroll wheel does not change on page appearance. Here is the link to mobiscroll select http://demo.mobiscroll.com/#display=inline&theme=android-ics&demo=dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Using `$('#city').val('3');` will put The third option 'Boston' as selected for example

Comment: `val` matches based on the value property of the <option> tag, which is "3" for Boston

Comment: Even though when I changed Bostont o 3, and submit it, it sends the 3rd option, the Mobiscroll wheel does not change on page appearance. Here is the link to mobiscroll select http://demo.mobiscroll.com/#display=inline&theme=android-ics&demo=dropdown

Comment: Have you tried
$('#select').scroller({
        preset: 'select',
        theme: 'android-ics',
        display: 'inline',
        mode: 'scroller',
        inputClass: 'i-txt'
    }).val('3');

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think the vanilla DOM method is what I'd go with:

```
$('#city')[0].options.selectedIndex = 3;
```

It should be mentioned that this and other solutions should be placed *before* you initialize mobiscroll. Working demo with mobiscroll: http://jsfiddle.net/DCaHK/1/

...On further thought, your first suggestion of adding `selected` to the option should have worked.  Updated my demo to do exactly that.  Autocomplete could prevent this from working properly in some browsers, so it's possible your issue is simply that you need to turn autocomplete off:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <select id="city" class="cities" data-role="none" name="City">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="1">Atlanta</option>
        <option value="2" selected>Berlin</option>
        <option value="3">Boston</option>
    </select>
</form>
```